# Is there any way to append to a specified column of a csv file in Bash?

Tags: bash, csv, append

(Neebe here) I want the output from a bash command, to be appended to a specific column (lets say column 3) in my scv file. Is there a way to specify which column to append when you write in .csv file? Could not find anything relavant. Thanks in advance.

```
echo "$variable" >> my_file.csv
```

Comment: `awk -F, -v var="$variable" '{$3=$3 var}1' file > newFile` ? Good luck.

Comment: Does the csv file contain quoted commas or backslashed commas/quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ",,$variable" >> my_file.csv
```

(same as `echo "1,2,3"` where `1` and `2` are empty and `3` is your `$variable`)

if `$variable` could contain commas/newlines - it's better to wrap it into quotes:

```
echo ",,\"$variable\"" >> my_file.csv
```

if `$variable` could contain double-quotes - use following:

```
echo ",,\"`echo "$variable"|sed 's/"/""/g'`\"" >> my_file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad